# How to run redis server with IPV6 interface?

Tags: redis

How to run redis server with IPV6 interface?

If the redis.conf is edited to bind IPV6, then following error is thrown.

```
Examples:
#
# bind 192.168.1.100 10.0.0.1
# bind 127.0.0.1 ::1
#
# ~~~ WARNING ~~~ If the computer running Redis is directly exposed to the
# internet, binding to all the interfaces is dangerous and will expose the
# instance to everybody on the internet. So by default we uncomment the
# following bind directive, that will force Redis to listen only into
# the IPv4 lookback interface address (this means Redis will be able to
# accept connections only from clients running into the same computer it
# is running).
#
# IF YOU ARE SURE YOU WANT YOUR INSTANCE TO LISTEN TO ALL THE INTERFACES
# JUST COMMENT THE FOLLOWING LINE.
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
bind fe80::f816:3eff:fe09:7895
```

Error message is-

> 826:M 09 Jul 08:16:46.355 # Creating Server TCP listening socket fe80::f816:3eff:fe09:7895:6379: bind: Invalid argument

Redis Server version - 4.0.6